# PHP MySQL hyperlink from selection

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, crud

I have a PHP CRUD system, were the user can select an option, I want the options to be external hyperlinks with target. I cannot work out where I can put the two links, is this possible with my code?

**index.php**

```
<td><?php echo $row['usertype'] ?></td>
```

**create.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="gd">User Type</label>
<select class="form-control" id="gd" name="gd">
<option>Administrator</option>
<option>NetMan</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**update.php**

```
<?php
$usertypes = array('Administrator' => 'Administrator', 'NetMan' => 'NetMan');
$selcted_usertype = !empty($row['usertype']) ? $row['usertype'] : "";
?>
<label for="gd">User Type</label>
<select class="form-control" id="gd" name="gd">
<?php
foreach ($usertypes as $user_type_val => $usertype_txt) {
$selected = ($user_type_val == $selcted_usertype) ? "selected='selected'" : "";
?>
<option <?php echo $selected; ?> value="<?php echo $user_type_val; ?>"><?php echo $usertype_txt; ?></option>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question. You want to redirect if user changes drop down value ?

Comment: No sorry, when the user sees the table on the index page, I want the text to be a hyperlink, so basically both options will be an external link

Comment: eventually I will have 10 options, all going to separate external sites

Comment: then why are you using select tag. Simply use anchor tag

Comment: The selection goes to my DB, an anchor wouldn't work would it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right you want a dropdown menu that when you click an option it takes you to an external website? If so this can do the job:

```
<select>
    <option title="google.co.uk" onclick="location.href='http://example.com'">Administrator</option>
    <option title="bbc.co.uk" onclick="location.href='http://example.com'">NetMan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No, here is my example, basically when they click netman I want it to go say google.co.uk, and administrator to bbc.co.uk
http://www.jayg.co.uk/oakpw/index.php

Comment: So when user clicks on the name it has to display something that says google.co.uk or bbc.co.uk?

Comment: No still to say the same names, netman and administrator, I just want those names to be external hyperlinks

Comment: No way to put hyperlinks inside select menu, you can use the method I said before.

Comment: Here you have a jsfiddle:  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KeepoN/jfgd493g) When you hover your mouse over the name, it displays the site it will go to and if you click, it will redirect you to that website.

Comment: Hi thanks for taking a look, it doesn't work though, on the example site, I have called it hyperlink test

Comment: You have to change the *example.com* to the page you want

Comment: I have done
    <option title="google.co.uk" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.co.uk'">Administrator</option>
source code says
     <td>Administrator</td>

Comment: Link should have the *http://* at the beggining because it's not a local link but an external one.

Comment: I do have http://www.google.co.uk, for some reason its not showing up on this site

Comment: Wait, do you have the options inside a `<select>`?